# Unexpected Token HTML error on IBM Domino Web application

Tags: html, lotus-domino, lotus

Working on a old IBM Lotus Domino web application - it is not XPages.

Page keeps throwing HTML errors on this line of HTML:

```
<tr valign="top"><td width="20"><img width="1" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""></td><font size="2" face="Arial"></font><td width="466" colspan="2"><img width="1" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""></td></tr>
```

Error says "Unexpected Token" and indicates between the font tags: `<font size="2" face="Arial"></font>`

Looks like designer is setting font size between `<td>` table boxes that it generates and I'm not seeing a way to remove the font setting.  Table is created in designer via Create, Table and not pass through HTML.

In a perfect world I would re-do application in XPages but not an option at the moment...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Very hard to guess without seeing the elements in question.

Is this table part of a rich text field, created by a user, or has it been created in designer?
If the latter is the case then you could try marking the entire table in deisgner then hit

***Edit >> Convert to HTML***

This will create true passthru HTML code for the selected elements converting them to their HTML counterparts, and thus you should be able to see the faulty `<font>` tag

Another option could be to export the data to DXL which is possible for both a design and a data element. Again in the resulting xml code you might be able to find the piece of code that's causing trouble.

Finally you could even try to reconvert the cleaned up code to its original format.

Good luck!